# PrensetationFramework calling WpfWebRequestHelper incomprehensibly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a very strange problem and I don't know how to analyze it. It occurs only on the system of our client and not on my machine. It occurs everytime the client restarts the software and opens a specific dialog for the first time...

The when the dialog is created, the software freezes for 100 seconds. I managed to get the callstack by attaching to the software and hitting break when the dialog is beeing created. It looks like wpf is doing a webrequest with a timeout of 100 seconds, but I dont understand why. We dont do any WebRequests in our code, PresentationFramework somehow decides it has to do a WebRequest.

Did Someone experience a similar problem or can imagine why this call happens every time this dialog is opened for the first time? Any hint could be helpfull...

The Callstack:

```
file:///C:/Windows/system32/spool/drivers/color/sRGB%20Color%20Space%20Profile.icm

TimeOut 100000


    ntdll.dll!00007fffc8f246d4()    Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!00007fffc653f310()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!00007fff7073069e()   Unknown
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) Unknown
    System.dll!System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()  Unknown
>   PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.Initialize(System.Uri profileUri, bool isStandardProfileUriNotFromUser)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.ColorContext(System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pixelFormat)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CreateCachedBitmap(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame frame, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSourceSafeMILHandle wicSource, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalette palette) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.FinalizeCreation()  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupFrames(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame> frames) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Frames.get()    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(System.Uri baseUri, System.Uri uri, System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.TrySharingValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, object value, string parentName, System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool allowRecursive, out System.Windows.PropertyValue? sharedValue)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.TrySharingProperty(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlType parentType, string parentName, MS.Utility.FrugalObjectList<System.Xaml.NamespaceDeclaration> previousNamespaces, out System.Windows.PropertyValue? sharedValue) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseNode(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Windows.TemplateContent.StackOfFrames stack, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.PropertyValue> sharedProperties, ref int nameNumber, out object newValue)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseNodes(System.Windows.TemplateContent.StackOfFrames stack, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.PropertyValue> sharedProperties, ref int nameNumber) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseTree(System.Windows.TemplateContent.StackOfFrames stack, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.PropertyValue> sharedProperties, ref int nameNumber)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseXaml()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.Template.set(System.Windows.TemplateContent value)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(object inst, System.Xaml.XamlMember property, object value)  Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx, System.Xaml.XamlMember prop, object value, bool onParent)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord key) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DeferredResourceReference.GetValue(System.Windows.BaseValueSourceInternal valueSource) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.TryProvideValueImpl(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference) Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension me, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ProvideValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)    Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord key) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Lookup(object key, bool allowDeferredResourceReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, bool canCacheAsThemeResource) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.FindResourceInEnviroment(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.TryProvideValueImpl(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference) Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension me, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ProvideValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)    Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream)    Unknown
```

EDIT:

I'm using a DataTemplate in this View:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type shared:PreviewPageViewModel}">
<Grid Background="White">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Image Source="{Binding PreviewPicturePath, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                 Stretch="Uniform" 
                 StretchDirection="Both"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Visibility="{Binding PicturePathValid, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"
                          BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                          BorderThickness="10"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Content="{Binding Path=FunctionViewAdapter}"
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource HintTemplateSelector}"
                          Visibility="{Binding ShowFallbackPreview, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                          Opacity="0.85">
  </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

The Bound Property is just a string:

```
  string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(panelPath);
  string panelPicturePath = Path.Combine(directory, "PreviewPicture.png");

  if (File.Exists(panelPicturePath))
  {
    PreviewPicturePath = panelPicturePath;
  }


  
     public class StringToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
  {
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (!(value is string valueString))
  {
    return null;
  }
  try
  {
    ImageSource image = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(valueString), BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    return image;
  }
  catch { return null; }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a picture in this dialogue? And what's the URL you've used for it look like?

Comment: @Andy The Request seems to look for this file: C:/Windows/system32/spool/drivers/color/sRGB%20Color%20Space%20Profile.icm

Comment: @Andy I updated my Post with a DataTemplate using an Image and the Bound Property for the ImageSource

Comment: Is that file readable on the users pc?

Comment: @Andy Yes it is. I also added the code of the Converter for the ImageSource

Comment: Icm us a new one on me. I'd consider including a png or jpg in the app instead. I'm doubtful about absolute url outside any apps own folder unless you completely control that machine.