# WPF TemplateSelector using Image fires Webrequest

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm running into a problem using `ItemTemplateSelector` with templates containing `Image`:

Example DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExampleDataTemplate">
<StackPanel>
  <Image Width="16" Height="16" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="pack://application:,,,/UI.Shared;component/Resources/ExampleImage.ico" />
</StackPanel>
```

I cannot fully explain why this happens, because it only happens now and then and only on some machines...

It seems like a WebRequest is fired with a timeout of 100sec, which causes our UI to freeze. This WebRequest is fired by .Net framework somehow.

The Stacktrace is:

```
    KernelBase.dll!00007fffc653f310()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!00007fff7073069e()   Unknown
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) Unknown
    System.dll!System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()  Unknown
>   PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.Initialize(System.Uri profileUri, bool isStandardProfileUriNotFromUser)  Unknown 
 
 
 
 PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.ColorContext(System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pixelFormat)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CreateCachedBitmap(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame frame, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSourceSafeMILHandle wicSource, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalette palette) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.FinalizeCreation()  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupFrames(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame> frames) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Frames.get()    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(System.Uri baseUri, System.Uri uri, System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.TrySharingValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, object value, string parentName, System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool allowRecursive, out System.Windows.PropertyValue? sharedValue)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.TrySharingProperty(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlType parentType, string parentName, MS.Utility.FrugalObjectList<System.Xaml.NamespaceDeclaration> previousNamespaces, out System.Windows.PropertyValue? sharedValue) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseNode(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Windows.TemplateContent.StackOfFrames stack, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.PropertyValue> sharedProperties, ref int nameNumber, out object newValue)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseNodes(System.Windows.TemplateContent.StackOfFrames stack, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.PropertyValue> sharedProperties, ref int nameNumber) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseTree(System.Windows.TemplateContent.StackOfFrames stack, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.PropertyValue> sharedProperties, ref int nameNumber)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TemplateContent.ParseXaml()    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.Template.set(System.Windows.TemplateContent value)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(object inst, System.Xaml.XamlMember property, object value)  Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx, System.Xaml.XamlMember prop, object value, bool onParent)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord key) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DeferredResourceReference.GetValue(System.Windows.BaseValueSourceInternal valueSource) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.TryProvideValueImpl(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference) Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension me, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ProvideValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)    Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord key) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(object key, ref object value, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object key, out bool canCache)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object key, out bool canCache) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Lookup(object key, bool allowDeferredResourceReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, bool canCacheAsThemeResource) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.FindResourceInEnviroment(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.TryProvideValueImpl(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool allowDeferredReference) Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension me, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ProvideValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)    Unknown
    System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream)    Unknown
    UI.Display.dll!UI.Display.Views.Display.DisplayView()   Unknown 

The bottom Line the Constructor of a View containing The TemplateSelector is called, which will for some reason start this Webrequest, can maybe anyone explain to me why this happens?
The Images are included in the project as `Resources` and deployed just like any other file.

the TemplateSelector is nothing special:
```

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
  var libItem = item as FunctionViewAdapter;
  if (libItem == null) return Unknown;

  switch (libItem.Type)
  {
      case MyType.Example:
          return Example;
    
      default:
          return Unknown;
  }
}
```

Comment: Resources are compiled into the exe ( or dll ) . That seems to differ from your description. You get that sort of error if they cannot be loaded. As to exactly why that is, you've not told us enough. Maybe they take too long to load. In other questions like this though, it turned out they weren't deployed correctly.

Comment: Is it the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75071012/1136211)?

Comment: @Andy What could be a reason for a resource compiled into the dll cannot be loaded or take to long to load? I still dont understand why a Webrequest is fired...

Comment: It is the ColorContext.Initialize method that makes a web request to load a color profile. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/ColorContext.cs,06b6b1c4f6a74ab7

Comment: @Clemens The Ctor of `ColorContext` calls initialize in any case, and there the WebRequest is fired in any case, did I get this right? So the Problem is the usage of ColorContext in the first place?

Comment: No idea what exactly is happening there, sorry.

Comment: Colorprofile. Maybe it's trying to find colours to use. Fwiw I use geometries for iconography. Paths where one colour shapes will work and drawing brush if  it won't. Vectors scale well  colours can be themed and I never hit weird issues on some computers.